# Reading JSON with Apache Spark - `corrupt_record`

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark

I have a `json` file, `nodes` that looks like this:

```
[{"toid":"osgb4000000031043205","point":[508180.748,195333.973],"index":1}
,{"toid":"osgb4000000031043206","point":[508163.122,195316.627],"index":2}
,{"toid":"osgb4000000031043207","point":[508172.075,195325.719],"index":3}
,{"toid":"osgb4000000031043208","point":[508513,196023],"index":4}]
```

I am able to read and manipulate this record with Python.

I am trying to read this file in `scala` through the `spark-shell`.

From this [tutorial](http://xinhstechblog.blogspot.be/2015/06/reading-json-data-in-spark-dataframes.html), I can see that it is possible to read `json` via `sqlContext.read.json`

```
val vfile = sqlContext.read.json("path/to/file/nodes.json")
```

However, this results in a `corrupt_record` error:

```
vfile: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [_corrupt_record: string]
```

Can anyone shed some light on this error? I can read and use the file with other applications and I am confident it is not corrupt and sound `json`.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Spark cannot read JSON-array to a record on top-level, so you have to pass:

```
{"toid":"osgb4000000031043205","point":[508180.748,195333.973],"index":1} 
{"toid":"osgb4000000031043206","point":[508163.122,195316.627],"index":2} 
{"toid":"osgb4000000031043207","point":[508172.075,195325.719],"index":3} 
{"toid":"osgb4000000031043208","point":[508513,196023],"index":4}
```

As it's described in [the tutorial](http://xinhstechblog.blogspot.be/2015/06/reading-json-data-in-spark-dataframes.html) you're referring to:

> Let's begin by loading a JSON file, where **each line** is a JSON object

The reasoning is quite simple. Spark expects you to pass a file with a lot of JSON-entities (entity per line), so it could distribute their processing (per entity, roughly saying).

To put more light on it, here is a quote form [the official doc](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#json-datasets)

> Note that the file that is offered as a json file is not a typical
>   JSON file. Each line must contain a separate, self-contained valid
>   JSON object. As a consequence, a regular multi-line JSON file will
>   most often fail.

This format is called [JSONL](http://jsonlines.org/). Basically it's an alternative to CSV.

Comment: Thanks @dl14. I'll have to think about how to prepare the input files in more depth

Comment: Visitors: make sure you read the last part of this answer:

"Note that the file that is offered as a json file is not a typical JSON file. Each line must contain a separate, self-contained valid JSON object. As a consequence, a regular multi-line JSON file will most often fail."

Answer (score 41):

As Spark expects "JSON Line format" not a typical JSON format, we can tell spark to read typical JSON by specifying:

```
val df = spark.read.option("multiline", "true").json("<file>")
```

Comment: It's not giving as expected and getting Null as below.
|     _corrupt_record|order_customer_id|order_date|order_id|order_status|
+--------------------+-----------------+----------+--------+------------+
|                   {|             null|      null|    null|        null|
|           "Sno": 1,|             null|      null|    null|        null|
|    "Date": "30/0...|             null|      null|    null|        null|

Comment: This worked for me, and the following is my code:


movie0 = "dbfs:/FileStore/movies/movie_0.json"
movie0DF = (spark.read              # The DataFrameReader
    .option("inferSchema", "true")  # Automatically infer data types & column names
    .option("multiline", "true")    # Since not each line is a separate JSON object, therefore, to avoid error, I need to declare this line
    .json(movie0)                   # Creates a DataFrame from JSON after reading in the file
 )

Answer (score 12):

To read the multi-line JSON as a DataFrame:

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder().getOrCreate()

val df = spark.read.json(spark.sparkContext.wholeTextFiles("file.json").values)
```

Reading large files in this manner is not recommended, from the [wholeTextFiles docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/SparkContext.html#wholeTextFiles-java.lang.String-int-)

> Small files are preferred, large file is also allowable, but may cause bad performance.

Answer (score 1):

I run into the same problem. I used sparkContext and sparkSql on the same configuration:

```
val conf = new SparkConf()
  .setMaster("local[1]")
  .setAppName("Simple Application")


val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

val spark = SparkSession
  .builder()
  .config(conf)
  .getOrCreate()
```

Then, using the spark context I read the whole json (JSON - path to file) file:

```
 val jsonRDD = sc.wholeTextFiles(JSON).map(x => x._2)
```

You can create a schema for future selects, filters...

```
val schema = StructType( List(
  StructField("toid", StringType, nullable = true),
  StructField("point", ArrayType(DoubleType), nullable = true),
  StructField("index", DoubleType, nullable = true)
))
```

Create a DataFrame using spark sql:

```
var df: DataFrame = spark.read.schema(schema).json(jsonRDD).toDF()
```

For testing use show and printSchema:

```
df.show()
df.printSchema()
```

sbt build file:

```
name := "spark-single"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.7"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.0.2"
libraryDependencies +="org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.0.2"
```