# Python conversion from JSON to JSONL

Tags: python, json, jsonlines

I wish to manipulate a standard JSON object to an object where each line must contain a separate, self-contained valid JSON object. See [JSON Lines](http://jsonlines.org/)

```
JSON_file =

[{u'index': 1,
  u'no': 'A',
  u'met': u'1043205'},
 {u'index': 2,
  u'no': 'B',
  u'met': u'000031043206'},
 {u'index': 3,
  u'no': 'C',
  u'met': u'0031043207'}]
```

`To JSONL`:

```
{u'index': 1, u'no': 'A', u'met': u'1043205'}
{u'index': 2, u'no': 'B', u'met': u'031043206'}
{u'index': 3, u'no': 'C', u'met': u'0031043207'}
```

My current solution is to read the JSON file as a text file and remove the `[` from the beginning and the `]` from the end. Thus, creating a valid JSON object on each line, rather than a nested object containing lines.

I wonder if there is a more elegant solution? I suspect something could go wrong using string manipulation on the file.

The motivation is to read `json` files into RDD on Spark. See related question - [Reading JSON with Apache Spark - `corrupt_record`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38895057/reading-json-with-apache-spark-corrupt-record/38895521#38895521)

Comment: That's not valid JSON input, nor valid JSON output. You are handling *Python objects* here, not JSON serialisation. Even if your output was valid JSON, it would not be valid JSONL because you have *trailing commas*.

Comment: Also, if the objects in the output would be valid JSON, there would be no trailing commas.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

Your input appears to be a sequence of **Python objects**; it certainly is not valid a JSON document.

If you have a list of Python dictionaries, then all you have to do is dump each entry into a file separately, followed by a newline:

```
import json

with open('output.jsonl', 'w') as outfile:
    for entry in JSON_file:
        json.dump(entry, outfile)
        outfile.write('\n')
```

The default configuration for the `json` module is to output JSON without newlines embedded.

Assuming your `A`, `B` and `C` names are really strings, that would produce:

```
{"index": 1, "met": "1043205", "no": "A"}
{"index": 2, "met": "000031043206", "no": "B"}
{"index": 3, "met": "0031043207", "no": "C"}
```

If you started with a JSON document containing a list of entries, just parse that document first with `json.load()`/`json.loads()`.

Answer (score 67):

The [jsonlines](https://jsonlines.readthedocs.io/) package is made exactly for your use case:

```
import jsonlines

items = [
    {'a': 1, 'b': 2},
    {'a', 123, 'b': 456},
]
with jsonlines.open('output.jsonl', 'w') as writer:
    writer.write_all(items)
```

(Yes, I wrote it years after you posted your original question.)

Comment: **items** is a list

Answer (score 10):

A simple way to do this is with the [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) command in your terminal.

To install `jq` on [Debian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian) and derivatives:

```bash
sudo apt-get install jq
```

[CentOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CentOS) and [RHEL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux) users should run:

```bash
sudo yum -y install https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm
sudo yum install jq -y
```

Basic usage:

```bash
jq -c '.[]' some_json.json >> output.jsonl
```

If you need to handle with huge files, I strongly recommend to use the `--stream` flag. This will make `jq` parse your JSON content in streaming mode.

```bash
jq -c --stream '.[]' some_json.json >> output.json
```

But, if you need to do this operation into a Python file, you can use `bigjson`, a useful library that parses the JSON in streaming mode:

```bash
pip3 install bigjson
```

To read a huge JSON file (in my case, it was 40 GB):

```py
import bigjson

# Reads JSON file in streaming mode
with open('input_file.json', 'rb') as f:
    json_data = bigjson.load(f)

    # Open output file
    with open('output_file.jsonl', 'w') as outfile:
        # Iterates over input json
        for data in json_data:
            # Converts json to a Python dict
            dict_data = data.to_python()

            # Saves the output to output file
            outfile.write(json.dumps(dict_data)+"\n")
```

If you want, try to parallelize this code aiming to improve performance. Post the result here :)

Documentation and source code: *[bigjson](https://github.com/henu/bigjson)*

Comment: As of now this answer only works with Debian and derivatives. Are there otheer possible installation instructions for other operating systems?

Comment: Yes, but is a quite long, so, follow this link to install on RHEL/CentOS:  https://www.cyberithub.com/how-to-install-jq-json-processor-on-rhel-centos-7-8/

Answer (score 0):

Note that a JSONL file is a compacted JSON file. You may need to pass separators without spaces:

```
with open(output_file_jsonl, 'a', encoding ='utf8') as json_file:
    for elem in rs:
        json_file.write(json.dumps(dict(elem), separators=(',', ':'), cls=DateTimeEncoder))
        json_file.write('\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an edit to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38915250/11479825) which takes into account the possibility of special symbols or using a different alphabet in the JSONL file. For example, I use Cyrillic and without the `encoding` and `ensure_ascii` parameters edited, I get really ugly results. I thought it could be useful:

```
with open('output.jsonl', 'w', encoding='utf8') as outfile:
    for entry in dataset_donut:
        json.dump(entry, outfile, ensure_ascii=False)
        outfile.write('\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

You might also get this done with RegEx search and replace, for example in VSCode, if you switch on RegEx and search for `\n`:

[image]

and replace all by nothing. Then save the changed json file as "myfile.jsonl".

That works if you have only one JSON in your file (which should be the default). If you have a list of JSONs, like in your example, you can still search and replace with RegEx, take the negative lookahead "?!", see Stack Overflow [Find 'word' not followed by a certain character](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31201710/11154841) with `\n(?!\s*\{)` so that you also skip the spaces after a linebreak:

[image]

And there you go:

[image]

Clean the rest of the unneeded characters as you showed it yourself, but take RegEx for it, and you could also do this RegEx replacement automatically with Python with the [`re` package](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) instead of doing this in VSCode by hand.

- Replace `^\[` with nothing to get rid of the first bracket "[".
- Replace `\]$` with nothing to get rid of the last bracket "]".
- Replace `\,$` with nothing to get rid of the trailing commas ",".
- Replace `^\s*` with nothing to get rid of spaces at the beginning of a line.

Out:

```
{u'index': 1,  u'no': 'A',  u'met': u'1043205'}
{u'index': 2,  u'no': 'B',  u'met': u'000031043206'}
{u'index': 3,  u'no': 'C',  u'met': u'0031043207'}]
```

Answer (score -1):

If you don't want a library, it's easy enough to do using JSON directly.

Source

```json
[
    {"index": 1,"no": "A","met": "1043205"},
    {"index": 2,"no": "B","met": "000031043206"},
    {"index": 3,"no": "C","met": "0031043207"}
]
```

Code

```py
import json

with open("test.json", 'r') as infile:
    data = json.load(infile)
    if len(data) > 0:
        print(json.dumps([t for t in data[0]]))
        for record in data:
            print(json.dumps([v for (k,v) in record.items()]))
```

Result

```
["index", "no", "met"]
[1, "A", "1043205"]
[2, "B", "000031043206"]
[3, "C", "0031043207"]
```

Comment: Your result is a valid JSONL in traditional CSV format, but the question clearly wants an output in key, value pairs e.g. `{"index": 1,"no": "A","met": "1043205"}`.