# Format JSON to one line per input

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, multi-document

I'm trying to make my json compatible with Google ML, which after some searching means having one line per input instance (`Input instances are not in JSON format.`)

How can I change my code to have only one line per instance? (`img` variable is the image I encoded to base64)

```
json.dumps({"inputs": {"b64": img}})
```

Comment: Can this thread help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38915183/python-conversion-from-json-to-jsonl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The format you're referring to is called json-lines (.jl for a file extension).
You can use the [json-lines](https://jsonlines.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) python package in place of `json.dumps`.