# Regex in "Find and Replace"; how to match \n (newline character)?

Tags: regex, jupyter-notebook

I'm not sure whether I couldn't find the correct way or this is a bug.
I wanted to check some reference manual but there doesn't seem to be one.

In Jupyter's **Find and Replace** screen, there's an icon `.*` to check when I want to use regex.
Mostly it works fine, but if I try to match a line break (`\n`), it does not match it unless it is that very character. For example, I want to match every line that **doesn't end with `,`** and join that line to the next one. I'd match `[^,]\n` and replace with `,`, which would remove the line break. I could try `[^,]$`, but replacing this wouldn't remove the line break.

How do I do this?

Comment: Perhaps like this `(?<!,)\\n`

Comment: It seems there is no way to match a line break there.

Comment: I hit this in search for something else, which goes far beyond the question. I was a bit lost with this when I tried to make linebreak signs show up as linebreaks so that the text is more readable in the Jupyter Notebook output. I tried to replace `\\n` with `\n` with `re.sub("\\n","\n",string)` and found that it is much easier: just `print()` your output, it will show the linebreaks so that the output is readable.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of variants of the new-line character.
**E.g.:** `\r` or `\n`

### Regex Pattern

Anyway, here is the pattern using lookahead to check if there is a comma before, and the variants of new-line character.

```
(?<!,)(\r?(\n|\r))
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/mvgHDv/1)**

[image]

Or in VSCode with an example from [Python conversion from JSON to JSONL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38915183/11154841):

```py
[{u'index': 1,
  u'no': 'A',
  u'met': u'1043205'}
 {u'index': 2,
  u'no': 'B',
  u'met': u'000031043206'},
 {u'index': 3,
  u'no': 'C',
  u'met': u'0031043207'}]
```

[image]