# Expected file to have JSONL format, where every line is a JSON dictionary. openai createFile for fine tune

Tags: openai-api, fine-tuning

I created file with name mydata.jsonl and I put on it these lines

```json
    {
        "prompt": "aa",
        "completion": "bb"
    }
    {
        "prompt": "cc",
        "completion": "dd"
    }
```

then in `index.js` I did this function

```js
    const { Configuration, OpenAIApi } = require("openai");
    const fs = require("fs");
    
    const configuration = new Configuration({
        apiKey: process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY,
    });
    async function getAiResponse(topic) {
        const openai = new OpenAIApi(configuration);
        const filename = 'example.txt';
        const fileContents = 'This is some example text.';
        const response = await openai.createFile(
            fs.createReadStream("mydata.jsonl"),
            "fine-tune"
        );
        console.log(response)
    }
    getAiResponse("ee");
```

when I run my code I got error

```
    Expected file to have JSONL format, where every line is a JSON dictionary. Line 1 is not a dictionary (HINT: line starts with: "{...").
```

I can't get where is the exactly the error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The JSONL format is where the each json object is sperated by a newline characater.

So your output should be:

```
{ "prompt": "aa", "completion": "bb" }
{ "prompt": "cc", "completion": "dd" }
```

i.e. one LINE per json object

Comment: Only to fetch those who did not know how to read this: if you have a JSON file with linebreaks, so that it is readable with its JSON tree, you should drop any linebreak that is only for nesting or spreading the branches of the tree. One whole JSON must be in just one line. Check [Python conversion from JSON to JSONL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77901751/11154841) more insight.

Answer (score 1):

You can also get this error if the file you upload is encoded as UTF8 with the Byte Order Mark (BOM) included - despite the JSONL payload being valid.

Their file parser obviously misinterprets the BOM (commonly, hex `EF BB BF`) as part of the document payload, and decides it's not valid JSONL.

A fast way to check the encoding is to load the file in a good text editor, and it will often tell you. This is from Notepad++, for example:

[image: NotepadPpBOM]

(Alternatively, just open it in a binary editor, and look for `EF BB BF` at the start)

See this other answer for how to remove the BOM:
[How can I remove the BOM from a UTF-8 file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45240387/how-can-i-remove-the-bom-from-a-utf-8-file)