# Convert to JSON format expected by Spark for creating schema for dataframe in Java

Tags: json, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I have test JSON data at following link

http://developer.trade.gov/api/market-research-library.json

When I am trying to read schema directly from it in following manner

```java
public void readJsonFormat() {
        Dataset<Row> people = spark.read().json("market-research-library.json");
        people.printSchema();
    }
```

It is giving me error as

```
root
 |-- _corrupt_record: string (nullable = true)
```

If it is malformed, how to convert it into format as expected by Spark.

Comment: Each json object should be in a single line for spark to create a dataframe out of it..

Comment: When its big file in such format,what are the options @philantrovert

Comment: The file that you have provided has only one json object. Will that be the case always. If yes then you can just read it as an rdd and do a replaceAll for newline character \n.

Answer (score 3):

Converting your json to single line.

Or set `option("multiLine", true)` to allow multiply line json.

Comment: `Dataset<Row> people = spark.read().option("multiLine", true).json("market-research-library.json")` It is still giving error.

Comment: To add, this will work for only one record per file.

Answer (score 1):

If [this](http://developer.trade.gov/api/market-research-library.json) is the only `json` you would like to convert to `dataframe` then I suggest you to go with `wholeTextFiles` api. Since the `json` is not in *spark* readable format, you can convert it to *spark* readable format only when whole of the data is read as one parameter and `wholeTextFiles` api does that.

Then you can `replace` the *linefeed* and *spaces* from the `json` string. And finally you should have required `dataframe`.

```
sqlContext.read.json(sc.wholeTextFiles("path to market-research-library.json file").map(_._2.replace("\n", "").replace(" ", "")))
```

You should have your required `dataframe` with following `schema`

```
root
 |-- basePath: string (nullable = true)
 |-- definitions: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- Report: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- properties: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- click_url: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- description: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- type: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- country: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- description: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- type: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- description: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- description: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- type: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- expiration_date: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- description: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- type: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- id: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- description: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- type: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- industry: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- description: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- type: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- report_type: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- description: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- type: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- source_industry: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- description: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- type: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- title: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- description: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- type: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- url: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- description: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- type: string (nullable = true)
 |-- host: string (nullable = true)
 |-- info: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- description: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- title: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- version: string (nullable = true)
 |-- paths: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- /market_research_library/search: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- get: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- description: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- parameters: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- description: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- format: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- in: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- required: boolean (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- type: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- responses: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- 200: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- description: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- schema: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- items: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- $ref: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- type: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- summary: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- tags: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |-- produces: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |-- schemes: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |-- swagger: string (nullable = true)
```

Answer (score 1):

The format expected by spark is JSONL(JSON lines) which is not the standard JSON. Got to know this from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38895057/reading-json-with-apache-spark-corrupt-record). Here's a small python script to convert your json to expected format:

```
import jsonlines
import json


with open('C:/Users/ak/Documents/card.json', 'r') as f:
    json_data = json.load(f)

with jsonlines.open('C:/Users/ak/Documents/card_lines.json', 'w') as writer:
    writer.write_all(json_data)
```

Then you can access the file in your program as you have written in your code.