# Unable to read json file from dbfs which inturn the data is getting corrupted in python spark

Tags: python, json, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, azure-databricks

I am unable to read json files from `dbfs` which is getting corrupted dataframe.

I have tried

```
dfx = spark.read.option("multiline","true").json("/FileStore/tables/vv.json")

dfx = spark.read.option("multiline", "true").json("/FileStore/tables/vv.json")
```

output

```
dfx:pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame = [_corrupt_record: string]
```

Comment: Please verify whether your json file is proper or corrupt. This error arises when you have corrupt json record.

Comment: yes json file is proper only but dataframe is getting corrupted @Imprathik could you please help me

Comment: it is working in local perfectly but not in databricks

Comment: encoding issue?

Comment: Have you checked this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38895057/reading-json-with-apache-spark-corrupt-record